# Laravel: enabling debug toolbar

Tags: php, debugging, laravel-4

First of all, let me state very clearly that I'm completely new to Laravel; I may be missing something totally basic.

I'm trying to get the debug toolbar from https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar to work. I've followed the instructions and have done the following:

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar:1.x
```

then add

```
'Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider',
```

to

```
app/config/app.php
```

and then

```
php artisan debugbar:publish
```

My "debug" flag in app/config/app.php is set to true.

The docs on [github](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) say that the debugbar output should be injected just before the HTML body tag, however I see no debugbar output and no relevant code when I do a "view source" in my browser.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Have you set `app/config/local/app.php` debug to `true`?

Comment: Yes, it's set to true.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is most likely, that your `app/storage` folder is not writable. Check the laravel log for errors. This solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, one problem could be **folder/file permissions** for `app/storage`.

Other solution could be the **name of your environment folder**.

Unless you are doing unit testing you shouldn't name your environment folder 'testing' (`config/testing`) or 'tests'.